# How to plot by taking x axis values from two different columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(55)
data <- rnorm(8)
date1 <- as.POSIXct("2018-06-18 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + 0:(length(data)/2-1)*60
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-28 10:30:00", tz = "CET") + 0:(length(data)/2-1)*60
dates <- append(date1, date2)

df1 <- xts(x = data[1:4], order.by = date1) %>%
  fortify.zoo()
colnames(df1) <- c("Date1", "Data1")

df2 <- xts(x = data[5:8], order.by = date2) %>%
  fortify.zoo()
colnames(df2) <- c("Date2", "Data2")

df <- cbind(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
                Date1      Data1               Date2        Data2
1 2018-06-18 10:30:00  0.1201391 2019-03-28 10:30:00  0.001908206
2 2018-06-18 10:31:00 -1.8123769 2019-03-28 10:31:00  1.188518494
3 2018-06-18 10:32:00  0.1515830 2019-03-28 10:32:00 -0.505343855
4 2018-06-18 10:33:00 -1.1192210 2019-03-28 10:33:00 -0.099234393
```

I am basically trying to plot Data1 and Data2 together in a same plot where the x axis are Date1 and Date2

My initial thought was to use reshape2::melt() but getting warnings like:

```
No id variables; using all as measure variables
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot2` you can add two lines with different aesthetics for each:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(Date1, Data1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Date2, Data2), color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: It was painfully simple but does exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: I actually tried to mark both answer as accepted but apparently it seems like it is not possible to mark both answers  as accepted. But I think I should mark this one as it is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data in long format, `arrange` them according to `Date` and then plot

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = names(.), names_to = c(".value", "temp"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d)") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Date, Data) + geom_line()
```

[image]

You can probably beautify the plot and add more details as needed.